# How to make Canvas fill up the center of BorderPane in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, scenebuilder

This is my code so far (done in SceneBuilder).

```
<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/16" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <top>
      <MenuBar BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
        <menus>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Close" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edit">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="Delete" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
          <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
            <items>
              <MenuItem mnemonicParsing="false" text="About" />
            </items>
          </Menu>
        </menus>
      </MenuBar>
   </top>
   <center>
      <Canvas fx:id="canvas" onMouseClicked="#createNode" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </center>
   <right>
      <ScrollPane fitToWidth="true" hbarPolicy="NEVER" minViewportWidth="138.0" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="375.0" prefViewportWidth="138.0" prefWidth="138.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <content>
            <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="140.0" prefWidth="133.0">
               <children>
                  <Label text="Graph Type" underline="true">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </Label>
                  <RadioButton fx:id="directedButton" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Directed">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <toggleGroup>
                        <ToggleGroup fx:id="graphType" />
                     </toggleGroup>
                  </RadioButton>
                  <RadioButton fx:id="undirectedButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Undirected" toggleGroup="$graphType">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </RadioButton>
                  <Label alignment="TOP_CENTER" text="Diagram Tools" underline="true">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets />
                     </VBox.margin>
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </Label>
                  <ToggleButton fx:id="selectButton" mnemonicParsing="false" selected="true" text="Select">
                     <toggleGroup>
                        <ToggleGroup fx:id="diagramTools" />
                     </toggleGroup>
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </ToggleButton>
                  <ToggleButton fx:id="nodeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Node" toggleGroup="$diagramTools">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </ToggleButton>
                  <ToggleButton fx:id="edgeButton" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Edge" toggleGroup="$diagramTools">
                     <VBox.margin>
                        <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                     </VBox.margin>
                  </ToggleButton>
                  <Label text="Diagram Actions" underline="true">
                     <padding>
                        <Insets bottom="5.0" left="5.0" right="5.0" top="5.0" />
                     </padding>
                  </Label>
                  <VBox alignment="TOP_CENTER" prefHeight="151.0" prefWidth="120.0">
                     <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="DFS">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="52.0" layoutY="41.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="BFS">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="53.0" layoutY="73.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Shortest Path">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="27.0" layoutY="102.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hamilton Path" />
                        <Button layoutX="24.0" layoutY="134.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Hamilton Cycle">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="22.0" layoutY="163.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Eulerian Path">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                        <Button layoutX="27.0" layoutY="191.0" mnemonicParsing="false" text="Eulerian Cycle">
                           <VBox.margin>
                              <Insets bottom="3.0" left="3.0" right="3.0" top="3.0" />
                           </VBox.margin>
                        </Button>
                     </children>
                  </VBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </content>
      </ScrollPane>
   </right>
   <left>
      <VBox prefHeight="375.0" prefWidth="119.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </left>
</BorderPane>
```

I have a toolbar made from a ScrollPane on the right side, and when the window is shrunk, the toolbar stays visible in the window. The top and left will be occupied, with the bottom empty. I want the center to be a canvas that shrinks and grows as the window size changes, to fill the rest of the space. But in SceneBuilder I can only set a width/height that is fixed.

How can I have the BorderPane's center Canvas just automatically fill whatever space isn't occupied, regardless of window size? Can it be done in SceneBuilder, or only in my Controller or the FXML file itself?

Edit: Here is my main class for sake of minimum reproducible example, although it just sets it up. The controller class `Controller` is essentially empty.

```
public class Main extends Application {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample1.fxml"));
        stage.setTitle("Sample 2");
        stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 500, 500));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. mind the __M__!

Comment: Is the FXML that I have not a minimum reproducible example? My Main and Controller class do nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: you don't expect _me_ to write the boilerplate to reproduce _your_ problem, do you ;) Anyway, the fxml is far from minimal - if you have a layout problem with sizing anything in the center of a BorderPane, there is no need for anything else except something in the center of a BorderPane. While a single component in any/all of the other regions might be okay (depends), many buttons, togglegroups, menuItems certainly are unrelated.

Comment: btw: what you want is the default behavior of a borderPane, make sure you read its api doc. And _do not_ hard-code any sizes (as you do f.i. in your scrollPane) - it's a no-no-never.

Comment: To make sure you understand this: `Canvas` _is not resizable_. That means the built-in layouts will never resize the canvas to fit the available space; the canvas' dimensions are solely dictated by its `width` and `height` properties. What James_D does is sort-of-but-not-really a hack, but it works for your purposes. You also have to redraw the canvas otherwise you'll lose information. Anything drawn "outside" the new dimensions is lost and will not auto-magically reappear if and when the canvas grows again. That likely means you'll need to separately keep track of drawing "operations".

Answer (score 2):

A `Canvas` is not a resizable node, so will not be resized by default. You have to arrange for `setWidth()` and `setHeight()` to be called (and you will likely want to repaint the canvas when you do this).

One option is to define a custom region to hold the canvas, and override its `layoutChildren()` method to resize and repaint the canvas. This might look like:

```
public class CanvasPane extends Region {
    private final Canvas canvas ;
    private Consumer<Canvas> repaint ;
    public CanvasPane() {
        this.canvas = new Canvas() ;
        getChildren().add(canvas);
        repaint = c -> {} ;
    }
    
    public Consumer<Canvas> getRepaint() {
        return repaint;
    }
    
    public void setRepaint(Consumer<Canvas> repaint) {
        this.repaint = repaint ;
    }

    public Canvas getCanvas() {
        return canvas ;
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void layoutChildren() {
        super.layoutChildren();
        double width = getWidth();
        canvas.setWidth(width);
        double height = getHeight();
        canvas.setHeight(height);
        repaint.accept(canvas);
    }
}
```

Now in the FXML:

```xml
<BorderPane>
    <center>
        <CanvasPane fx:id="canvasPane" />
    </center>
</BorderPane>
```

and in the controller:

```
public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private CanvasPane canvasPane ;

    public void initialize() {
        canvasPane.setRepaint(this::repaintCanvas);
    }

    private void repaintCanvas(Canvas canvas) {
        // example canvas painting:
        double width = canvas.getWidth() ;
        double height = canvas.getHeight() ;
        GraphicsContext graphics = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
        graphics.setFill(Color.web("#868c8c"));
        graphics.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
        graphics.setFill(Color.web("#08cd4f"));
        graphics.fillRect(20, 20, width-40, height-40);
    }
}
```

Now when the border pane is resized, it will allocate the appropriate space to the `CanvasPane` (which is a `Region`). The `layoutChildren()` method will be automatically invoked and the canvas will be resized to its region (and repainted, if you supply a `repaint` in the controller).

Comment: Bit of warning though: Anything drawn on the canvas that ends up "outside" the new dimensions is lost, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Slaw That is correct. Fully re-drawing the canvas after resizing is advisable.